# How to create a link like Faceebook groups?

Tags: php, facebook, url

I would like to know how to create links, like Facebook uses on their group pages.

> https://www.facebook.com/groups/356149784477344/

Instead of having ex listgroups.php?id=3334

I have read about that you can change httpd.conf, but that was for permalinks. like wordpress style.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: That would depend on your application used to host the server, and not the language. For apache, it would be [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use mod_rewrite module in apache (if you are using apache of course). Try this small tutorial..

http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/